# How to collect mutliple elements of a List<Map<String, Object>> into single Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to collect multiple elements of a List<Map<String, Object>> into Map<String, Object>.

I was trying:

```
        Map<String, Object> generalMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map<String, Object> map : jsonList){
            for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                generalMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
```

, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: So us  example input and output

Comment: in the code snippet you are not trying concat, but collect entries to another map

Comment: Yes, I would like to collect them to one Map<String, Object>.

Comment: It's better to add an example of input and output to clarify the question. What is the type of `jsonList` ? If there are multiple same key in multiple map what is your expected output ?

Comment: what do you mean with it only joins the first element of a list? which list

Comment: From my understanding, you are trying to merge to maps `generalMap` and `jsonList`. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps) you have some approaches.

Comment: I've edited the question. I just want to collect all Maps from List into single Map.

Comment: Explain what you mean with "it doesn't work". What is the input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0):

By "join", do you mean you are trying to get all your key-value pairs in all the maps in the list into a single map?
If yes, your code is correct. As maps store values based on unique keys, it may be the case that your keys are duplicate.